# loopback.js extend existing calls

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

How can I extend a call for a model.

E.g when I expose the model products I get all available default rest calls for that model.

e.g 
Patch products updates the product.

I want to extend the existing logic only for that model without creating another remote method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need remote hooks. More [documentation here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html)